# Add score in <input> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am doing a quiz that consists of 3 questions and each question has 3 options. Only one question is displayed on the screen at a time. For answer a the value is 2 points, for answer b the value is 1 point and for answer c the value is 0 points. I try to make a summation of each question so that at the end a message with the final score is displayed, but I'm stuck. Here my code so far.

Thank you in advance!

```js
const qData = [
    {
        question: "Question1",
        a: "Yes",
        b: "No",
        c: "Maybe",
    },
    {
        question: "Question2",
        a: "Always",
        b: "Sometimes",
        c: "Never",
    },
    {
        question: "Question3",
        a: "100%",
        b: "50%",
        c: "0%",
    }
    
]

const questionE1 = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a-text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b-text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c-text");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("siguiente")

let currentQuiz = 0;

loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz() {
    const currentQuizData = qData[currentQuiz];

    questionE1.innerText = currentQuizData.question;
    a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a;
    b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b;
    c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c;

}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    currentQuiz++;
});

const numericalValues = new Array();
numericalValues["a"]= 2;
numericalValues["b"]= 1;
numericalValues["c"]= 0;

function getscore() {
     var puntos = 0;
     var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
     for(var i=0; i<answer.length; i++)
     {
         if(answer[i]) {
             puntos = numericalValues[answer[i].value];
         }
     }
     return puntos;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Quiz</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="score">
    <h2 id="question">Question text</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer"><label id="a-text" for="a">Question</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer"><label id="b-text" for="b">Question</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer"><label id="c-text" for="c">Question</label></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="siguiente">Next</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<p id="result">Final Score</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("answer")` You have no `id="answer"` in the HTML. Also, `document.getElementById()` just returns a single element, you can't loop over it. Where are you testing which radio box they selected? Did you mean `if (answer[i].checked)`?

Comment: I suspect you meant `document.getElementsByClassName("answer")`

Comment: You never call `getScore`.

Comment: `answer[i].value` None of radio buttons have a value. I think you meant `answer[i].id`. Or you should change `id="a"` to `value="a"`

Answer (score 1):

I've rebuild your structure of data by adding `answer` property to each object, otherwise there"s no way to know if the user answers the right answer!
Also checked if the user choose an answer before move to the next!

```js
const qData = [
  {
    question: "Question1",
    a: "Yes",
    b: "No",
    c: "Maybe",
    answer: "a",
  },
  {
    question: "Question2",
    a: "Always",
    b: "Sometimes",
    c: "Never",
    answer: "b",
  },
  {
    question: "Question3",
    a: "100%",
    b: "50%",
    c: "0%",
    answer: "c",
  },
];
let currInd = -1;
let rightAnswers = 0;
function renderQuestion() {
  ++currInd;
  if (currInd != qData.length) {
    const question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerText = qData[currInd].question;
    const { a, b, c } = qData[currInd];
    document.getElementById("a-text").innerText = a;
    document.getElementById("b-text").innerText = b;
    document.getElementById("c-text").innerText = c;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(
      "result"
    ).innerText = `You got ${rightAnswers} right answers, and you lost ${
      qData.length - rightAnswers
    } questions`;
    document.querySelector(".container").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".result").style.display = "block";
  }
}
//render first question:
renderQuestion();

document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);

function nextQuestion() {
  let options = [...document.querySelectorAll(".answer")];
  let gaveAnswer =
    options.map((option) => option.checked).filter(Boolean).length == 1;
  let answerMapping = {
    0: "a",
    1: "b",
    2: "c",
  };
  //check the answer before move to the next question
  if (gaveAnswer) {
    let answerInd = options
      .map((option) => option.checked)
      .map(Number)
      .findIndex((ind) => ind == 1);
    let isRightAnswer = answerMapping[answerInd] == qData[currInd].answer;
    rightAnswers += isRightAnswer;
    renderQuestion();
    //empty the current checked option
    options.forEach((option) => {
      option.checked = false;
    });
  } else {
    alert("choose an answer");
  }
}
```

```css
.result {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="score">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <ul id="options">
        <li>
        <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer" /><label
            id="a-text"
            for="a"
        ></label>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer" /><label
            id="b-text"
            for="b"
        ></label>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer" /><label
            id="c-text"
            for="c"
        ></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="result">Final Score: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

*If you don't understand something comment it below, I'll explain to you!*

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use your fixed code but I have doubts. My goal would be if they select all "a" options they have 6 points at the end, and if they select all "c" they have 0 points, and if they select all "b" they have 3 dots at the end, and so on if they select mixed.
But in your code is just 1 or 3 points depending on right answers... I mean, there is no right answer is just a result depending on your points... thank you so much in advance :)